# Make e-mail field from single product page review form not required

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to either remove or disable requirement of the woocommerce single product review **e-mail field,** but keep the name field.

If you uncheck the option "users have to enter name and email to comment" both of fields get removed. Making it easy to leave a review, but are likely not to be trusted by other users since there is no name next to it. If you make e-mail required, users are not likely to leave a review at all.

So far I tried:

1. Edit single-product-reviews.php by removing the "required" attribute and get_option from the fields:

```
                        'author' => array(
                            'label'    => __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'type'     => 'text',
                            'value'    => $commenter['comment_author'],
                            'required' => '',
                        ),
                        'email' => array(
                            'label'    => __( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ),
                            'type'     => 'email',
                            'value'    => $commenter['comment_author_email'],
                            'required' => '',
                        ),
                    );
```

2. Unset the e-mail field via filter (works but field is still required):

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'remove_email_field', 9 );
function remove_email_field( $fields ){
    unset ($fields['email']);
    return $fields;
}
```

3. Make email field not required via filter (not working, breaks review form):

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_fields', 'email_field_not_required');
function email_field_not_required( $fields ){
    $fields['email']['required'] = false;
    return $fields;
}
```

The end result should look something like this (no e-mail field but required name):

[image]

Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to hide email fields from a comment form rather than remove it.

```
function hide_email_field_on_comment(){

    if( !is_admin() && is_product() ){
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .comment-form-email{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <?php
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_email_field_on_comment', 10, 1 );
```

[image]

Then you can modify `single-product-reviews.php` and pass random email to value. so it will not give the required field error for email.

```
$fields = array(
    'author' => array(
        'label'    => __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'     => 'text',
        'value'    => $commenter['comment_author'],
        'required' => $name_email_required,
    ),
    'email'  => array(
        'label'    => __( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'     => 'email',
        'value'    => 'test@test.com', // pass random email.
        'required' => $name_email_required,
    ),
);
```

Now you have to remove email from comment when a comment is inserted. for that, you can use the `preprocess_comment` filter hook.

```
function remove_dummy_email( $commentdata ){
    unset( $commentdata['comment_author_email'] );
    return $commentdata;
}
add_filter( 'preprocess_comment', 'remove_dummy_email', 10, 1 );
```

[image]